# How to properly display weather station JSON data on Leaflet map from Synoptic API?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapping, gis, weather

I'm trying to display a map of weather stations in Alaska from a MesoWest (now Synoptic) API with their temperature and wind speed on a Leaflet map. I've seen some examples online but they're all very old and result in errors.

Here is what I have in my .js:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([64.666, -147.101], 8);
var basemap = L.tileLayer.provider('Stamen.Terrain').addTo(map);

var mesoMarkersGroup=new L.LayerGroup(); 
$.getJSON('https://api.synopticdata.com/v2/stations/latest?&token=[MY TOKEN]&within=1440&obtimezone=utc&output=json&units=temp|f,speed|mph&state=ak&country=us&status=active&vars=air_temp,wind_speed&varsoperator=and', function (data) {
    L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
});
map.addLayer(mesoMarkersGroup);
```

The link should return raw .JSON data.

Here is a snippet of some of what the link shows if I limit it to one station:

```
{"UNITS":{"wind_speed":"Miles\/hour","air_temp":"Fahrenheit"},"QC_SUMMARY":{"QC_CHECKS_APPLIED":["sl_range_check"],"TOTAL_OBSERVATIONS_FLAGGED":0.0,"PERCENT_OF_TOTAL_OBSERVATIONS_FLAGGED":0.0},"STATION":[{"STATUS":"ACTIVE","MNET_ID":"1","PERIOD_OF_RECORD":{"start":"2002-11-05T00:00:00Z","end":"2021-12-09T07:15:00Z"},"ELEVATION":"433","NAME":"Fairbanks, Fairbanks International Airport","DISTANCE":0.0,"STID":"PAFA","SENSOR_VARIABLES":{"wind_speed":{"wind_speed_value_1":{"period_of_record":{"start":"","end":""}}},"air_temp":{"air_temp_value_1":{"period_of_record":{"start":"","end":""}}}},"ELEV_DEM":"419.9","LONGITUDE":"-147.87611","STATE":"AK","OBSERVATIONS":{"wind_speed_value_1":{"date_time":"2021-12-09T07:53:00Z","value":0.0},"air_temp_value_1":{"date_time":"2021-12-09T07:53:00Z","value":10.94}},"RESTRICTED":false,"QC_FLAGGED":false,"LATITUDE":"64.80389","TIMEZONE":"America\/Anchorage","ID":"4620"}],"SUMMARY":{"DATA_QUERY_TIME":"1.08480453491 ms","RESPONSE_CODE":1,"RESPONSE_MESSAGE":"OK","METADATA_RESPONSE_TIME":"152.322053909 ms","DATA_PARSING_TIME":"0.256776809692 ms","TOTAL_DATA_TIME":"1.34587287903 ms","NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS":1}}
```

I just want a dot on the map that shows wind and temperature :(

Comment: How is it supposed to work for you if the format that is returned is json, not geojson. Look here [geojson](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/)

Comment: @Grzegorz T. Okay, that makes sense. I thought leaflet would do that automatically. It should be able to take the .json though since it has lat/long data in it. So I did something like this and it seems to work $.getJSON('LINK', {
    },
    function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.STATION.length; i++) {
            var stn = data.STATION[i]
            var circle = L.circle(L.latLng(stn.LATITUDE, stn.LONGITUDE), {
                color: 'black',
                fillColor: '#f03',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                radius: 5000
            }).addTo(map);

Comment: The documentation specifies the exact format that can be passed to L.geoJson. In the future you can provide links to codepen.io or codesandbox.io with the reconstructed code so it's better for people who want to help.

Comment: See this api has the ability to use geojson, and you just need to read the documentation ;) Just set `output=geojson`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned above, it is enough to add the appropriate parameter to the api `output=geojson` call. Below is the use of api:

```js
var map = L.map("map").setView([0, 0], 13);

L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

fetch("https://api.synopticdata.com/v2/stations/latest?radius=KHOU,50&limit=10&output=geojson&vars=air_temp&within=100&token=70c1dfd9b68d4511a0a8283cc6f0f972")
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    const jsonLayer = L.geoJSON(data);
    jsonLayer.addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(jsonLayer.getBounds(), {padding: [50, 50]});
  });
```

```css
*,
:after,
:before {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Ah... I thought from the Getting Started page on [Synoptic's dev site](https://developers.synopticdata.com/mesonet/v2/getting-started/) you could only return JSON. Their [query builder](https://developers.synopticdata.com/mesonet/explorer/) doesn't even list geoJSON as an option! But the other code I had was [this](https://paste2.org/zYIgdsdn). What you did worked though, thank you!